# Is there a way to convert a memo field to a text field in Access 2010 in an expression?

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I have two tables (each in an Access DB) -- called LinkedTable1 and LinkedTable2 linked to my working Access database.  I got them on my computer after downloading them from a SharePoint site (Actions -> Open with Access).

In each of LinkedTable1 and LinkedTable2 there's a Memo field that contains a GUID.  This GUID links the two tables.

I'd like to use these GUIDs in a query, but when I try to JOIN them within Query Design, I get told that I cannot join on Memo fields.

I tried creating an expression to convert the field to a Text field:

`GUID_Text:  CStr( Left$( [LinkedTable1]![GUID_Memo], 255 ) )`

I also tried converting the field to a GUID:

`GUID:  GUIDFromString( [LinkedTable1]![GUID_Memo] )`

I did this on each of the linked tables.  Both time, when I tried to execute the query, I got a type mismatch error.

Any ways around this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to perform the JOIN by creating a saved query for each table to convert the Memo field to Text, and then JOIN the *queries*. For test data in [Table1]

```
ID  GUID_Memo                               Description
--  --------------------------------------  -----------
1   {453EE643-BFE5-4D8B-B9F1-2B66C71E609A}  Table1: foo
2   {80BC2B94-7AC2-4956-959B-E8B624F06502}  Table1: bar
```

and [Table2]

```
ID  GUID_Memo                               Description
--  --------------------------------------  -----------
6   {453EE643-BFE5-4D8B-B9F1-2B66C71E609A}  Table2: foo
7   {80BC2B94-7AC2-4956-959B-E8B624F06502}  Table2: bar
```

where [GUID_Memo] are true `Memo` fields, the saved queries [Query1]

```sql
SELECT Left([GUID_Memo],100) AS GUID_Text, Table1.Description
FROM Table1;
```

and [Query2]

```sql
SELECT Left([GUID_Memo],100) AS GUID_Text, Table2.Description
FROM Table2;
```

when joined together

```sql
SELECT 
    Query1.GUID_Text, 
    Query1.Description AS Description1, 
    Query2.Description AS Description2
FROM 
    Query1 
    INNER JOIN 
    Query2 
        ON Query1.GUID_Text = Query2.GUID_Text;
```

results in

```
GUID_Text                               Description1  Description2
--------------------------------------  ------------  ------------
{453EE643-BFE5-4D8B-B9F1-2B66C71E609A}  Table1: foo   Table2: foo
{80BC2B94-7AC2-4956-959B-E8B624F06502}  Table1: bar   Table2: bar
```